# Using FTP from PHP CURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I can't figure out how to use CURL's FTP, specifically, how to issue FTP commands from my PHP code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE,array('CWD bussys/','LIST')); /* ?!! */

    echo '<hr><pre>'.htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch)).'</pre><hr>';
?>
```

In my example above I want to get a directory listing of bussys, but instead I get a listing of the main (FTP root) directory.

By the way, I tried the following combinations:

- `LIST bussys/`
- `CWD bussys, LIST -a`

Comment: have u tried using the PHP FTP functions instead of using CURL for it?

Comment: Yeah, but they cause certain problems. Plus, CURL FTP is preferred over the built-in PHP FTP functions for several reasons (including speed and performance).

Comment: Try the suggestions from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178425/download-a-file-from-ftp-using-curl-and-php

Answer (score 6):

I searched for a way to change working directory also, but couldn't find anything.

What ultimately worked for me was including the folder in the `CURLOPT_URL`.  Additionally, the folder alone wasn't enough, I had to include a trailing forward slash `/`.

So if what worked for me will work for you, then setting the following url structure and `CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY` should get you the contents of `bussys/`.

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/bussys/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTPLISTONLY, TRUE);`

And I didn't need the `CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE` `CWD` option to get the nested directories contents.

Comment: This solved same issue for me. I recommend adding a CURLOPT_TIMEOUT in seconds.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to work with curl, use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST options.

See below example code.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://192.168.0.129");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "sru:sru");
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1) ;
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'CWD /a'); // change directory
curl_exec($curl);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'MLSD'); // get directory list
$ftp_result=curl_exec($curl);
echo $ftp_result;
```

It returns

```
type=dir;modify=20130319024302; test
```

test is sub directory of a.

I think you have to use ftp_connect rather.