# cURL FTP connection

Tags: php, curl, ftp

We have a cron-job running on our server, that downloads data from MeteoConsult, which is some dutch weather-report company... thing...

Anyway, basically the script downloads an XML file using FTP via cURL which then gets parsed using SimpleXML. A week or two ago, it decided to die randomly and kill our joy of watching the weather. I'm clueless. The FTP data are correct and have been verified. The Meteo server doesn't block the IP address of the server the cron-job is running on.

Why the developer used cURL to download a file over FTP is truly a mystery for me. When I run the script on a different server it seems to work.

With that information, I assume that either we're using an "old fashioned" way and doesn't work with new cURL / PHP versions though I couldn't find any information about that, or our server's firewall is blocking the connection.

Here's (a part) the script:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"ftp://username:password@ftp.meteocon.nl/file.xml");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV, 0);

$xml = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl);
curl_close($curl);

// At this point, $xml is NULL
```

Is there anything wrong with this script? If not, do you guys have an idea what the problem could be?

```
PHP version: 5.2.12
libcurl version: 7.20.0
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried checking for errors? http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php

Comment: @Znarkus Good point! `string(24) "couldn't connect to host"`. Still doesn't quite explains why though.

Comment: Can you connect to the FTP from the server, via command line `curl` or `ftp`?

Comment: @Znarkus Problem is solved, but I can't delete the question yet. Nor can I flag my own answer as correct answer at this point. I have to wait 2 days. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host recently tighten up the security of their servers. They had to add the URL in the white-list.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer provided at [download a file from ftp using curl and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178425/download-a-file-from-ftp-using-curl-and-php)

Basically you need to separate out the URI and the authentication settings like so:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp.meteocon.nl/file.xml"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
curl_exec($curl);
```

I have not tested this, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is IPv6 FTP PASV related. Try to turn on/off (or test as completelly remove) the CURLOPT_FTP_USE_EPSV option.
You can check this for more info: [IPv6 FTP PASV problems](http://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2007-08/0406.html)