# Curl returns Failed connect to <url>:80

Tags: php, curl

I am using [Curl](https://php.net/curl) for the first time in PHP. Here is my code.

```
<?php
    function curl($url){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        echo curl_getinfo($ch) . '<br/>';   //returns "Array"
        curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';    // returns "7"
        curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';    //returns "Failed connect to www.epcc.ed.ac.uk:80; No error"
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
        }


        $url = 'http://www.epcc.ed.ac.uk/education-training/general-training/upcoming-courses-and-events/';
        $output = curl($url);
        var_dump($output);  // returns "bool(false)"
?>
```

I have added the output what I get in comments in the code.

Can anyone tell me where is the problem? Is it a general issue or any proxy issue.

Thanks

Comment: Possible fix here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host

Comment: I think its a problem in your end. I get a result when trying your code. Can you open the webpage in your browser at all?

Comment: agreed with ronnie, it works for me on local setup (crap deb7).

Comment: I can open the link in my browser but it doesn't work when tried using CURL. I don't have opening the url in my browser. I assume I will have to set proxy in my code as I am behind proxy. Am I right?

Comment: paste the output of `curl_getinfo()` in your original question

Comment: I have written the answer next to it in comments. It returns the word "Array" without quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a proxy issue, as you suspected. If you connect to your network via a proxy, this will need to be set-up for curl.

This may help -> [Use Curl via Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9247672/3365207).