# Can't access file via PHP script, but can open it in browser

Tags: php

I have an url with RSS feed:

```
$url = 'http://www.myurl.com/sth?format=RSS';
```

I can open it in a browser without a problem. But

```
$feed->load($url)
```

returned 'false'. So I started investigating:

```
$ch = curl_init($file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$retcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);           
print curl_error($ch); // prints 'couldn't connect to host'
echo "CODE: ".$retcode; // $retcode is 0

$file_headers = get_headers($file);
echo $file_headers[0]; // is null
```

So, what can be the reason for such behaviour? Is some port blocked on myurl.com server? Is there a way to work around it (like create local copy of the file and work on it)?

Comment: could be no outgoing http connections allowed, could be a security setting, could be the remote server blocking your request. simple test: log into a shell on the server and try to `telnet www.myurl.com 80` and see if that connects.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: whats your hosting platform?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the site has some block for external connections implemented, such check for User-Agent, referal...

Answer (score 0):

maybe the server is doing some sniffing and doesnt serve anything on that url if it finds that curl is doing the work. you could try phantomJS and/or Selenium to get around such filters. Selenium has PHP bindings.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on CentOS (known issue on that flavour), do the following to test and make sure that's the not issue. later you can later issue specific filtering.

```
> emacs  /etc/selinux/config

locate following line
SELINUX=enforcing

Change this to
SELINUX=disabled
```

save the file and try again. it could be your localhost firewall if you can open it in a browser without a problem.

if this is an issue, set SELinux back to `enforcing` and issue

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect`

if you want httpd to be able to connect to tcp ports

Comment: This seems like it'd have fairly significant security implications that should be mentioned beyond "just do this!".

Comment: this seems like you haven't read my post? its to test and set it back to what it was, then use setsebool to allow httpd to figure out the problem.

Comment: It seems like you're not aware that SO has timestamps. You added that five minutes after my comment, so for obvious reasons, my comment did not deal with your *future* revisions.

Comment: rgr that to timestamps