# What is wget cron command equals to running the code through browser

Tags: php, zend-framework, cron, wget

My question is I have a wget cron job setup in cpanel and it does not work.. I mean the cron job is running but the work inside code is not happening...

But when I just enter the same URL in the browser the code get executed successfully...

So can some one tell me what is exactly equal situation command in wget as like we are performing a browser request

current cron looks like this. I am using Zend php framework

```
wget -b http://www.**myhost**/index/db-backup
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs made my cron to check for any errors?  These logs are in `/var/log/syslog` for Ubuntu

Comment: try it without the `-b`

Comment: It was early without -b but still won't work

Answer (score 1):

If you have curl enabled - you could just do this as your cron entry:

```
 curl http://www.**myhost**/index/db-backup
```

Then it is exactly as if you hit the address in a browser

If you dont want any data dump from the cron output - you can do this

```
 curl http://www.**myhost**/index/db-backup > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Seems like something is blocking your connection. Probably the same reason `wget` is not working. Are there any firewall restrictions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host

Answer (score 1):

The http request using wget and your browser may differ. That may cause some troubles in application. You may want to debug your http request with `wget --debug URL` option. 
For simple crawling for cron purpose wget has spider option `wget --spider URL`

http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html