# curl_exec return false while try to connect to URL

Tags: php, android

i am trying to create a push notification application which will send messages from the server to the users device.

for now i get the registration ids but when i run the curl_exec function i get the following error:

```
Curl failed: couldn't connect to host
```

i don't know why is that and i made some checks and when i try to change the URL to "google.com" is pass.
from my browser if i try to reach the original URL its redirect me to :
"https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/"
this is the php code:

```
    <?php
class GCM {

    function __construct() {

    }
    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once 'connection.php';

        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );

        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' .GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found that my server containing a firewall which blocking my outgoing connections. so i just open it and its working now.
this is the solution which helped me to solve the problem with link to the relevant answer.

CURL error code 7 (CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT)
is very explicit ... it means Failed to connect() to host or proxy.

The following code would work on any system:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://google.com");    // initialize curl handle
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
print($data);
```

If you can not see google page then .. your URL is wrong or you have some firewall or restriction issue

[this link help me to resolve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)