# Hitting URL every minute in background

Tags: php, linux

I want to hit a URL of my application through cron job. I have done the following things:

1) Opened the terminal

2) Did `crontab -e` which gives me an editor that allows me to put statements

3) Pasted the URL that needs to be hit after specified interval of time:

```
curl -s  http://www.example.com/controller/function_to_execute
```

This cron job will run every minute

4) Saved the cron and again on terminal did `crontab -l`, and I could see my cron

This scheduler isn't working, don't know why. I tried `curl` on the terminal directly expecting some output, but after 5 minutes it gives me the result

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

If I hit my URL on browser directly then my job gets successfully executed!

Have I made some mistake while making entry in the cron?

Comment: have you tried this? `* * * * * curl -s  http://www.example.com/controller/function_to_execute`

Comment: Yes I have tried with * * * * that is the proper way to execute the cron for every minute. Is it some permission related issue that I am getting curl: (7) couldn't connect to host when I CURL on terminal directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)

Comment: Referring to one of the solutions to disable (SELINUX=enforcing to  SELINUX=disabled) I have checked that file and SELINUX is already showing as disabled.

Comment: It sounds like you have two separate issues here, `cron` and `curl`. Try putting something in `cron` like `* * * * * touch /tmp/cron_ok`.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create the php script and run the script using cronjob 
1)Open terminal and type crontab -e  
2)Edit the file and write the following code to run the php script in background

```
*/1 * * * * php /yourpath/yourphpfile.php
```

3) Create yourphpfile.php and write the code to hit the url
  you have to execute and test the yourphpfile.php before doing cronjob

Comment: Tried it out, No luck :(

Answer (score 1):

Whoops!..tried to just curl www.google.com and gave the following output in form of HTML tags "302 Document has moved", Also I am not able to ping the application itself from the terminal but it is accessible publicly

So cron job getting executed is out of question :P