# PHP Curl can't fetch data from any url

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am trying to fetch some data with this code

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 return $data;
 }
  $file= file_get_contents_curl('www.website.com/page');
```

and I get errorno 7

```
CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT (7)
Failed to connect() to host or proxy.
```

I have tried with www.google.com too, but i've got the same error.

I guess that i have to change something on server (linux), but i dont know what.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it with http:// in front?

Comment: did you try "curl google.com" on the command line?

Comment: i have http:// in front. It works from localhost. I dont know how to try "curl google.com" on the command line on my hosting server.

Comment: Do you actually have access to the command line on the server?

Comment: No, i can only upload files. I have access to phpmyadmin, i don't know can i fix something from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is already answered before. You can checked this question:

[How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)
If you can't catch google ,You must checked your firewall.

Comment: I have checked that url in answer, but i don't know how to disable selinux on my hosting server. I haven't mention that my code work on localhost.