# curl give error curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Tags: php, curl

I am trying  to execute curl command from php using exec() function but it gives me that error

> curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

This is my code:

```
$command = "curl http://localhost:6821/schedule.json 
           -d project=default -d search=".$_POST["search_type"]." 
           -d url='".$url_info["url"]."' -d domain='".$domain."' -d               
           city='".$url_info["city"]."' -d state='".$url_info["state"]."' 2>&1";

$return = exec($command);
echo $return;
```

I am beginner with curl. I search and found there is a php library could perform curl command functionality but I don't know how to transfer this command line to php code using the curl library.

Comment: probably isn't the current problem, but it will probably be your next problem: you're not escaping arguments for curl correctly here. search=".escapeshellarg($_POST["search_type"])."~~

Comment: where does it fail in this code?
<?php
$sck=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
if($sck===FALSE){
 die('socket_create failed!');
}
if(!socket_set_block($sck)){
 die("socket_set_block failed!");
}
echo "connecting to server..";
if(!socket_connect($sck,'127.0.0.1',6821)){
 die("socket_connect failed!");
}
echo "connected!";
?>

Comment: I tried it @hanshenrik and it gives me this warning

connecting to server..
Warning: socket_connect() [function.socket-connect]: unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in /var/www/rssfeed/test_sac.php on line 16
socket_connect failed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be your issue. Because curl is set to port 6821, it may be blocked. Does the same request to port 80 work? Check out this other thread.

[How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)