# Google Maps API not working with server side code but works client side

Tags: php, google-maps, curl, google-maps-api-3

I'm generating a URL such as:

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=143+Blackstone+Street%2C+Mendon%2C+MA+-+01756&key=***********

If I open this in browser, I'm getting a result successfully. However, if I use the same URL using `curl`, I'm getting:

> error:couldn't connect to host

Here is my PHP code

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".urlencode('143 Blackstone Street, Mendon, MA - 01756')."&key=***********";    
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100,            
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($response);
```

#### UPDATE

I came across a term called as `server key` and `browser key` when using the Google APIs. Howerver, in the API manager, I can't seem to see where to set or change the API type.

Comment: Google server does not allow request directly from the server unless it is triggered using browser agent. What are you trying to achieve by CURL + Google Map?

Comment: @AnandG Getting the lat and lng from a text address.

Answer (score 1):

You are urlencodeing parts of the url that need to be in plain text.

Only urlencode your parameters

```
<?php
$address = urlencode("143 Blackstone Street, Mendon, MA - 01756");
$key = urlencode("************");
$ch = curl_init();
$options = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&key=".$key,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 100,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch))
{
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($response);
```

Comment: My bad. I posted the old code. I was URL encoding the parameters only and not the entire URL.

Comment: In which case you shouldn't get the error you gave as that code works as long as you have a valid key

Answer (score 0):

If you're hitting an 'couldn't connect to host' error message from curl it sounds like the problem may not be on the Google Maps API side and instead be on the proxy / networking side. A connection to maps.googleapis.com should always be possible, regardless of key type or url params.

I would look into the steps suggested here: [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)