# Send cURL request via PHP

Tags: php, html, json, curl, request

How do I go about sending this information:

```
// build an associative array
$data["username"]="a";
$data["password"]="b";
$data["msisdn"]="447123121234";
$data["webhook"]="http://1f89e4a8.ngrok.io/testDir/getPost.php";

// turn it into json formatted string
$json_data=json_encode($data);
```

To the API:

```
$url = "http://ms.4url.eu/lookup";
```

Using cURL,  I have currently been using :

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 201 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}


curl_close($curl);
```

Of which I get the results (NGrok):

> GET /testDir/curlPost.php HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, */*
>
> Accept-Language: en-GB
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79
>   Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393
>
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
>
> Host: f0946724.ngrok.io
>
> X-Forwarded-For: 92.11.143.199
>
> 200 OK HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>
> Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2016 00:48:20 GMT
>
> Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/7.0.9
>
> X-Powered-By: PHP/7.0.9
>
> Content-Length: 161
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> Error: call to URL http://ms.4url.eu/lookup failed with status 0,
>   response , curl_error Failed to connect to ms.4url.eu port 80:
>   Connection refused, curl_errno 7

As well as the error stated from cUrl:

> Error: call to URL http://ms.4url.eu/lookup failed with status 0,
>   response , curl_error Failed to connect to ms.4url.eu port 80:
>   Connection refused, curl_errno 7

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: first of all, does ` http://ms.4url.eu/lookup` reachable..? cause i've never seen http status code 0.

Comment: Yes a http request of the data stated in               Json format returns POST /testDir/getPost.php HTTP/1.1 host: 1f89e4a8.ngrok.io accept: application/json content-type: application/json content-length: 198 Connection: close X-Forwarded-For: 5.44.233.221 {"id":"ea26d0b2-b839-46b9-9138-50cc791bab47","msisdn":"447123121234","status":"Success","networkCode":"23471","countryName":"UK","countryCode":"GBR","network":"O2","networkType":"GSM","ported":"No"}.

Comment: uh not the generated request, but the ms.4url.eu/lookup.. because your [curl error is no 7, that means unable to connect](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html), and someone ever asked [such case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host) in stackoverflow before.. could you try to invoke curl to another domain, like google - if it also fails, check your firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the Error I was getting is due to the server expecting a Https(443) connection and not Http(80), this was easily solved by changing the URL to https://ms.4url.eu as opposed to http://ms.4url.eu when sending the request with cURL.