# CURL: path after hostname and port

Tags: php, curl, php-curl

I want to send JSON data to http://localhost:3000/certificates using curl in PHP

Here is what I do:

```
$url = 'http://localhost';
$ch = curl_init($url);
$jsonData = array(
    'certno' => 'AB1234',
    'issueDate' => 'asdasd',
    'type' => 'asdasdasd'
);
$jsonDataEncoded = json_encode($jsonData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 3000); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

How to add /certificates ? I cannot simply put it in url http://localhost/certificates right?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`.

Comment: so, where should I add /certificates ?

Comment: `$url = 'http://localhost/certificates';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);`

Comment: Failed to connect to localhost port 3000. How do you consider the port?

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 3000);`

Comment: I have put port before. still getting the same error curl_errno 7

Comment: Paste the whole error code. I also recommend you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18097615/2518525

Comment: Error: call to URL http://localhost/certificates failed with status 0, response , curl_error Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused, curl_errno 7. Btw, I'm using node js with expressjs in my server