# Curl returns empty response on the first api call, but return response on the second call

Tags: php, api, curl

I use curl to make a call to the API like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();

if (isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'session=' . $_COOKIE['session']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query_url);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
}
else {
    $result = 'Cookie is expired';
}
curl_close($curl);

print $result;
```

Then I run this PHP file to test it and during testing when I load the file I receive nothing, when I restart the page I get the data that I need. When I use it with javascript behavior is similar.

When I test it with Postman, it works just fine.

Why doesn't it wait for a response and returns it to me then, but rather sends me the empty page first time around and only after page reload it returns a proper response?

Edit: JSON return is quite huge so it usually take a server around 1.5-2 seconds to return it

Comment: You might check the HTTP status code of the first call, possibly with [curl_getinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php#example-5404).

Comment: @showdev keep getting 0 on the first request and then 200 on the second, thanks for the hint

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the API, not your code.

Comment: Hm, then maybe check [`curl_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php).

Comment: @showdev it returns 7. A workaround I found is using:
    `$http_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($http_code == 0) {
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
    }`, but I think it is a bad approach

Comment: An error code of "7" indicates: "Failed to connect() to host or proxy". See [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9923212/924299).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it is an issue with the server I am trying to connect to and there is not much I can do except for this workaround:

`if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 0) {
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
}`

Here is the final snippet:

```
$curl = curl_init();

if (isset($_COOKIE['session'])) {
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'session=' . $_COOKIE['session']);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $query_url);
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 0) {
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
    }
}
else {
    $result = 'Cookie is expired';
}
curl_close($curl);

print $result;
```