# How to resolve AWS HTTP error: cURL Error 7 CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT

Tags: amazon-s3, symfony4, ovh

I'm creating a website on Symfony 4.

I've download aws/aws-sdk-php package to connect to aws3 and league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3 to upload file.

Trying to add a picture to AWS S3 bucket I get this error :

> Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://sftest-jobboard.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/?prefix=company%2Ffouquet%2Favatar%2Favatar-org-5de7c60517092.png%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: cURL error 7:  (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

In Service.yaml

```
Aws\S3\S3Client:
        arguments:
            -
                version: 'latest'
                region: 'eu-west-3'
                credentials:
                    key: '%env(AWS_S3_ACCESS_ID)%'
                    secret: '%env(AWS_S3_ACCESS_SECRET)%'
```

My IAM User policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:ReplicateObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::sftest-jobboard",
                "arn:aws:s3:::sftest-jobboard/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This configuration works in localhost but it doesn't work anymore when I deploy my site on OVH.

I'have tried all the solutions proposed in this topic : [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host) but nothing works.