# Maven Spring boot application - Connection refused error with 8080 port

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, centos, devops

I am trying to run a spring boot application with a prerequisite of java 8 and maven (both are installed) properly. 
while running test:

`mvn clean test`

it ran completed as SUCCESS and also

`mvn spring-boot:run`​ completed success

But when I execute the below command locally
`curl http://localhost:8080/actuator/info​`

> connect was refused error with curl 7

I am using CENTOS on GCP and has enabled the traffic for port 8080 in the security in GCP.
Can anyone help with this, is there I am missing?

Comment: Check spring boot application logs. Look for the URL and port in which the app is published.

Comment: can you please specify the location or path of logs becuase i have checked 8080 is free no other services are running on that port.

Answer (score 1):

“`CURL ERROR 7 Failed to connect to Permission denied`” error is caused, when for any reason curl request is blocked by some firewall or similar thing.

Please check if this link helps you: [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)

Also check if your port 8080 is already in use. There may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).