# Getting response 0 from CURL PHP request

Tags: php, php-curl

I'm trying to use a proxy to access pages but when I try without the proxy the page give 200 response and I get the data, if I try with proxy I get a 0 response and no data.  I have tried many different proxies I've found online. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

```
header( 'Cache-Control: max-age=60' );

$url = "https://hidester.com/what-is-my-ip-address";
echo "<br/>Search URL: ".$url."<br/><br/>";

// Get page
get_page($url);

var_dump(get_page($url, "193.202.8.57:8085"));


function get_page($url,$proxy = NULL)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); // return headers 0 no 1 yes
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // return page 1:yes
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200); // http request timeout 20 seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); // Follow redirects, need this if the url changes

    if($proxy !== null)
    {
        echo "<br/> Trying proxy: {$proxy}";
        // no need to specify PROXYPORT again
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);

        // to make the request go through as though proxy didn't exist
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2); //if http server gives redirection responce
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt"); // cookies storage / here the changes have been made
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // false for https
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip"); // the page encoding

    $data = curl_exec($ch); // execute the http request
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);

    echo "<br/>Response: {$info["http_code"]} URL: {$info["url"]}<br/>";

    curl_close($ch); // close the connection
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: you don't appear to specify a proxy port

Answer (score 0):

If you tweak your function a little to include the `port` it appears to work OK

```
function get_page( $url, $proxy = false, $port=false ){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 200);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    if( !empty( $proxy ) && !empty( $port ) ){
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 0 );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, $port );
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.7) Gecko/20070914 Firefox/2.0.0.7");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies.txt");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
```

Using the same url you gave but a differet proxy and port

```
$url='https://hidester.com/what-is-my-ip-address/';
$proxy='137.74.144.21';
$port=8080;
```

And calling like this:

```
$res=get_page( $url, $proxy, $port );
printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res,true));
```

Using a different `curl` function with additional options for a verbose output might help you diagnose whether or not the problem lies with GoDaddy hosting or not. If you download a copy of `cacert.pem` and edit the path below you should get more detailed information about the request.

```
<?php

    function curl( $url=NULL, $options=NULL, $headers=false ){
        $cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
        $vbh = fopen('php://temp', 'w+');

        /* get cacert.pem from here */
        /* https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html */
        $res=array(
            'response'  =>  NULL,
            'info'      =>  array( 'http_code' => 100 ),
            'headers'   =>  NULL,
            'errors'    =>  NULL
        );
        if( is_null( $url ) ) return (object)$res;

        session_write_close();

        $curl=curl_init();
        if( parse_url( $url,PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
        }
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL,trim( $url ) );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '' );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, true );
        curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $vbh );

        if( isset( $options ) && is_array( $options ) ){
            foreach( $options as $param => $value ) curl_setopt( $curl, $param, $value );
        }
        if( $headers && is_array( $headers ) ){
            curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
        }
        $res=(object)array(
            'response'  =>  curl_exec( $curl ),
            'info'      =>  (object)curl_getinfo( $curl ),
            'errors'    =>  curl_error( $curl )
        );
        rewind( $vbh );
        $res->verbose=stream_get_contents( $vbh );
        fclose( $vbh );
        curl_close( $curl );
        return $res;
    }





    $url='https://hidester.com/what-is-my-ip-address/';
    $url='https://www.whatismyip.com/';
    $url='https://api.ipify.org?format=json';

    $proxy='137.74.144.21';
    $port=8080;



    $options=array(
        CURLOPT_PROXY           =>  $proxy,
        CURLOPT_PROXYPORT       =>  $port,
        CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL =>  true
    );

    $res=curl( $url, $options );
    if( $res->info->http_code==200 ){
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res->response,true));
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res->verbose,true));
        printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($res->info,true));
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I still get a response of 0 and a blank page with your updates. If I remove the proxy I get the correct page. I am running this on my godaddy server, could it be a configuration issue?

As seen here: http://graphicport.net/processing/test.php

Comment: when you use exactly the same details as above or the original ip & port from your question? I don't believe that the ip given (`193.202.8.57`) is live

Comment: I used what you show:

$url='https://hidester.com/what-is-my-ip-address/';
$proxy='137.74.144.21';
$port=8080;

Comment: Testing this with a different url endpoint but same proxy confirms this works OK when compared with a regular browser visit to https://api.ipify.org/?format=json

Comment: Then I think GoDaddy is not allowing it for me.

Comment: I tried adding curl_errno($ch); and it is giving Error Code 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host

Comment: I did the edited code you included with the cacert and had to remove $res->info->http_code==200 for any results.  You can see at http://graphicport.net/processing/test.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206158/discussion-between-ramraider-and-bicycle).