# PHP Laravel, Apache Server: "Curl ErrNo: 0. Curl Error: Failed to connect to my.website.com:443; Operation Now In Progress"

Tags: php, laravel, curl, server, operation

I have an apache server with centos distribution that I have put a PHP Laravel project on using git. It uses cURL requests to fetch and execute data gotten from endpoints. When I run this on my local virtual machine, it works perfectly. When I run it on my

Here is my code, note the cURL requests:

```
//NOTE: $this->headers = ["Authorization: Bearer " . myServerAccessToken];
 //sets URL and $curl
 public function getAdmins() {
   $adminsURL = "https://my.test.instructure.com/api/v1/accounts/1/admins?per_page=20";
   $curl = curl_init();

   self::requestCurl($curl, $adminsURL, $this->headers);
   $resp = curl_exec($curl);
   //dd($resp); //shows false
   return self::setHeaders($curl);
 }

  //cURL request function: used to set the value of $curl as seen in other functions
 public function requestCurl($curl, $url, $headers) {
     return curl_setopt_array($curl, [
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
       CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_URL => $url,
       CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
       CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
       CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
       CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE
     ]);
   }


//returns "curl errno: 0. Failed to connect to my.test.instructure.com:443; Operation now in progress
 //gets the data from a successful curl request, and returns said data
public function setHeaders($curl) {
  echo "<h1>SetHeaders()</h1>";
  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  $header_size = curl_getinfo( $curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE );
  $header = substr( $resp, 0, $header_size );
  $body = substr( $resp, $header_size); //$header_size
  $code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  if (curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) != 200) {
    echo "<h3>Curl errno: " . curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . "</h3>";
    echo "<h3>Curl error(): " . curl_error($curl) . "</h3>";
    dd($body);
    return null; 
  }
  $data = json_decode($body, true);
  return $data;
}
```

I can run this code on my local machine and it works perfectly. No complaints, full success. But when I run it on my apache server with a centos distribution, it falls apart. This output is what I get instead:

> "SetHeaders()"
>   "Curl errno: 0"
>   "Curl error(): Failed connect to my.test.instructure.com:443; Operation now in progress"
>
> "" [dd($body) returns an empty string]

====

I've looked up currl errno: 0 and I've looked up curl error 443, but 
The closest I've seen to a problem similar to mine is this page here:

> [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)

But from what I can tell, I already have the suggested solution in my code (CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE).

I suspect the problem is with the server itself, but I do not know enough of it to say what. I have looked at the /etc/hosts folder on my server, but I've been told it is configured correctly. With that in mind, what more can I try to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my server network had a proxy set. I was able to circumvent it by adding two lines to my curl_setopt_array request:

```
       public function requestCurl($curl, $url, $headers) {
           return curl_setopt_array($curl, [
             CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
             CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT => TRUE,
             CURLOPT_URL => $url,
             CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
             CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => TRUE,
             CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
             CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
             CURLOPT_PROXY => "https://my.proxy.url", //your proxy url
             CURLOPT_PROXYPORT => "my_proxy_port_number", // e.g 3333

             CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
             CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, 
             CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE
           ]);
         }
```