# Payment Method Connectivity issue on live server

Tags: laravel, curl, server, payment, ubl

I'm working on a project, I implemented the payment method it works locally properly but when I host my project on a live server it's not connected to the payment method server. It's showing an error (cURL error 7: Failed to connect to demo-ipg.ctdev.comtrust.ae port 2443 after 549 ms: Couldn't connect to server.)

I tried different scenarios but not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You've given no technical details, so the only thing we can suggest is to look at all the other examples that turn up if you search for your error message, eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve cURL Error (7): couldn't connect to host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922562/how-to-resolve-curl-error-7-couldnt-connect-to-host)

Comment: I think your live server is not allowing to open 2443 port. so, you should allow 2443 port for out going request.