# Compress and download from 3rd party ftp server using php

Tags: php, ftp

I'm downloading files from 3rd party ftp server using php. But file is more then 15mb. So it took more time to download. I have an idea to compress and download on the fly from ftp server. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to download the original file, one way or another. You can `zip` it with PHP, but **only** after you download the original file to your server. What you are asking is it the source server can compress it for you, which with `FTP` is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have one doubt, I have increased ftp connection time out. But due to global setting , it's not getting update. I have set it via ftp option method. Is there anyother way?

Comment: Consider the answer I just posted. `CURL` is a much better way to do this. Also, please consider marking the answer that helps you the most as "accepted." It is much appreciated. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: i'm getting premature end error. what to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to download the original file, one way or another. You can `zip` it with PHP, but only after you download the original file to your server. What you are asking is it the source server can compress it for you, which with `FTP` is not possible.

Consider using `CURL` to download the file from the FTP server. It's much more resiliant.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$file = fopen("file.zip", 'w'); ##where you want to save it
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "ftp://ftp.sunet.se/file.zip"); #input
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $file); #output
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$_FTP[username]:$_FTP[password]");
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($file);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1178425/1415625)