# Error downloading file via cURL

Tags: php, curl, ftp, download

I want to download a file from an ftp server via cURL.
Here is my function:

```
function getFile($remotefolder, $remotefile, $localfile) {
    $url  = "ftp://xxxxx.de/" . $remotefolder . "/" . $remotefile;
    $fp   = fopen($localfile, "w+");

    $handle = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 0);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "<Username>:<Password>");
    $result = curl_exec($handle);

    $info = curl_getinfo($handle);

    curl_close($handle);
    fclose($fp);

    print_r($info);
}
```

If I execute that on my pc everything works fine. But when I ran the code on the server it gaves me the following output and the file was not downloaded:

```
output server
=============
Array
(
    [url] => ftp://xxxx/xxxx/xxx.log.gz
    [content_type] =>
    [http_code] => 257
    [header_size] => 0
    [request_size] => 0
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.357453
    [namelookup_time] => 0.002011
    [connect_time] => 0.011153
    [pretransfer_time] => 1.357439
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

If you please further information, please let me know.

Thanks in advance,

Dennis

Comment: have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178425/download-a-file-from-ftp-using-curl-and-php

Comment: yes i've read this post and came up with the posted codesnippet. my problem is that this works on my testmachine perfectly, but not on my server. And i don't know why the http-code is 257 (on my testmachine the code is 226, which is correct).

Comment: If it's a shared hosting maybe there are some limitations with their setup. What version is the server running?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your http_code response, 257 is the code for "PATHNAME" created, which could mean that the file doesn't exist, or that your path may be incorrect.

Test it with a different URL that you know exists.

Comment: thx for your answer. I've checked the URL's on both systems and they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the order of the arguments. This is what I use in one of my classes that is dependent on a file located on an FTP server:

```
$fh = fopen('downloads/' . self::ZIP, 'w');
$ch = curl_init(self::FTP . self::PATH . '/' . self::ZIP);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, self::USERNAME . ':' . self::PASSWORD);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: thx for your answer. i've tried it this way but the result is the same